# What is the difference between a cascade and a waterfall?

Tags: hiking, waterfalls

I thought about asking this question on English Language and Usage, but decided not to because I want answers from people who are familiar with cascades and waterfalls in reality, not just in the abstract.  Moreover, the definitions aren't very helpful.

From [The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28381?rskey=BcBgeg&result=1#eid), a cascade is:

> Usually, a small waterfall; esp. one of a series of small falls,
>   formed by water in its descent over rocks, or in the artificial works
>   of the kind introduced in landscape gardening.

And from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226176?rskey=rxCETm&result=1#eid), a waterfall is:

> A cascade of water falling from a height, formed when a river or
>   stream flows over a precipice or ledge; (also) a garden water feature
>   resembling this.

Much of my hiking has been done in the Sierra, especially Yosemite, where waterfalls and cascades of every size abound.  I have always thought of a waterfall as water that flows over a lip and then falls freely.  And a cascade as water that may flow quite steeply downhill but remains in contact with the underlying rock or streambed.  I would never describe Nevada Falls, for example as a cascade, nor would I describe the cascades that flow over the bare granite at roughly the 8,000 foot level of Yosemite Creek as waterfalls.

Is there a difference between the two in TGO in other parts of the world, or have I made up a distinction that is not commonly used in TGO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Example of both](http://wallpaper-wallpapers.com/281-cascade-pictures.html)
[image]

Note in the high background, that is a waterfall.  In the foreground is the cascade.  One part fills before the other does.

The picture below shows a cascade.

[image: Another example of just a cascade]

Key difference between the two: in a waterfall, water moves only downward, while in a cascade, it moves both downward and onward, like stairs

Answer (score 3):

> Waterfall-- Water falls vertically and without obstruction from a distinct feature, generally more than 1 m high and often across the full channel width
>
> Cascade-- Fast flow with a smooth boundary and turbulent flow over boulders or bedrock. Flow is in contact with the substrate and exhibits upstream convergence and downstream divergence

[ECOSPHERE “Fluvial biotopes influence macroinvertebrate biodiversity
in South-East Asian tropical streams”December 2016 v Article e01479](https://docsbay.net/fluvial-biotopes-influence-macroinvertebrate-biodiversity-in-south-east-asian-tropical-streams)